# How is this a nullpointerexception?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm really confused: I'm simply trying to add the names of each object in an `ArrayList` to another `ArrayList`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < availableParts.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < namesOfIngredients.size(); j++){
         if (availableParts.get(i).getName() != namesOfParts.get(j)){
             namesOfParts.add(availableParts.get(i).getName());
         }
    }//middle if statement makes sure there are no repeats
}
```

EDIT: I realize namesOfIngredients is null. However, I need it to start null -- this is how I am copying over the names. Can this just not be done this way?

Comment: which line do you get an NPE?

Comment: the inner for loop (the one with j).

It might help to mention namesOfIngredients is previously blank

Comment: One may want to use a Debugger?

Comment: You're going to have many other issues with this code. Here's the things I see right off the bat. When you check `namesOfParts.get(j)` you'll probably get an `indexOutOfBounds` exception since you haven't put anything in that list the first time you check it. You're going to get tons of duplicates because every time you find an item that has a different name in the namesOfParts list you're adding another instance of `avaliableParts.get(i)`. Hopefully this will save you some headaches in the future :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your edit - how do you declare namesOfIngredients?

It should be

```
Object namesOfIngredients = new Object();
```

not

```
Object namesOfIngredients;
```

Comment: Thanks. This is actually my problem. Sorry for not mentioning how it was initialized.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure that

1. both lists `availableParts` and `namesOfIngredients` are not `null`
2. The list that you're adding elements to (`namesOfParts`) has been properly initialized with a constructor (is not `null`).
3. All elements inside these lists are not `null`

And remember that String comparison is done with [`String.equals()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29). Checking equality (`==`) on two String objects will only return true if they are the same instance.

As a side note, you could consider using [`List.contains()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) in order to find out if a certain part's name is on the `namesOfIngredients` list. Also, maybe it's a typo, but you should be checking for an [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) at `namesOfParts.get(j)` in that equality check.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to look at namesOfParts in the loop itself, but in the definition of the loop you're going to the length of namesOfIngredients. Is one of them null? I bet one is.

Answer (score 0):

availableParts.get(i) is probably null and therefore a getName() call results in a NPE.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know: we can't see how `availableParts` and `namesOfParts` are initialized.

But we can tell you how to find out.  Add print statements like this:

```
print "Before I try it"
print availableParts.get(i)
print namesOfParts(availableParts.get(i))
print "done"
```

when it NPE's you'll see exactly which one did the deed.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be invoking a number of methods within your loop, without checking that the object  on which you are invoking it is NULL or not. It is ALWAYS advisable to do so (especially, if you are not sure about the contract of the object returned by a given method)

So, basically, whenever you do something like `object.method()` and/or `object.method1().method2()`, ensure that `object` and/or `object.method1()` is NOT NULL before invoking follow-up methods on their return values.

Also, you could break calls in the following manner, to better debug and catch NPEs at the exact location:

```
Object returnObj = object.method1();
Object anotherReturn = returnObj.method2();
```